# In-memory integration tests and Environment Variables -- .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables, integration-testing

We can execute a test server for integration testing. Something like:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968788/how-do-i-run-in-memory-integration-tests-using-xunit-net-and-asp-net-5) or the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing)

Fine.

However, I can't pass environment variables to the test server.
I can set the environment with `UseEnvironment("Development")` but not add variables.
It should be possible, but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone Knows how this can be done?

---

The environment variables would carry dev logins for a 3rd party API our code base needs.
For unit tests we mock this 3rd party API.
A solution for my specific problem can be to mock this for integration tests as well, thus removing the need for environment variables, but even so the question remains.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set an environmental variable programmatically.

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("key", "value");
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx) writes that `SetEnvironmentVariable(string, string)`...

> Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process... Because the environment variable is defined in the environment block of the current process only, it does not persist after the process has ended.

Comment: Totally forgot about that. I use it to read the variables. Thanks!

Comment: Not working in Azure DevOps pipelines with ubuntu hosted agent. Any other ideas ?