# Set environment variable via launchSettings.json. in Test Project

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to run my end to end tests against the real environment using VS2019 in the IDE. The tests are located in separate test project within the main solution.

So I was trying to load environment variables using below two methods:

**Method 1**

Update `launchSettings.json` in the test project

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "My.Endpoint.Tests": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ServerName": "Apim"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Method 2**

Create below cmd file and add it to the project and then call same in `Build Events - Pre-build event command-line:` in the test project properties.

```
set ServerName=Apim
```

Unfortunately none of the above methods can read the given environment variable when execute the tests via `VS2019 IDE`

Comment: Do you mean that you  want to set the environment variables in the tested project and read the given environment variable when execute the tests ?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: a similar problem has already been reported to aspnet team in GitHub https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/1089, please vote for it.

Comment: Any update on this @SMPH??

Comment: possible duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035649/2097243